# How the make PDF fit the height - ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf, angular8

I am using `ng2-pdf-viewer` in my Angular 8 application.

I would like to show the PDF fit to the height of the container regardless of the width. So, PDF must take all of the height as we can do by selecting `Page Fit` from the zoom option in Mozilla's PDF (link [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)):

[image: example of required situation]

Here is what I have got right now:
[image]

My code for `ng2-pdf-viewer` is:

```
            <pdf-viewer
            [src]='"./assets/images/userFiles/" + file.fileName'
            [original-size]="false"
            [render-text]='false'
            [show-all]="false"
            style="display: block; height: 100%;"
            (after-load-complete)='afterLoadComplete($event)'
            (page-rendered)='pageRendered($event)'
            (pageChange)='pageChange($event)'

            ></pdf-viewer>
```

I have tried countless things for days to get this working. `fit-to-page`, giving `height` to all of the containers and much more.

Let me know, what is the best way to get it done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of efforts, I have found a way for making PDFs stretch to the height of container. I don't know whether it is good approach or not, but it is working great in my scenario.

1. Add following `css` in your main `style.scss` or `style.css`:

```
.ng2-pdf-viewer-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

2. Get `ng2-pdf-viewer` component into your component like this:

```
// other imports
import { PdfViewerComponent } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';


export class YourComponent{

  @ViewChild(PdfViewerComponent, {static: false})
  private pdfComponent: PdfViewerComponent;

// other code
}
```

3. Then use `(page-rendered)` event function to edit the `currentScaleValue` of the `pdfViewer`. Please check code below:
   **In html file:**

```
<div style='position: relative; height: 100%;'>

            <pdf-viewer [src]='"./assets/images/userFiles/" + file.fileName'
            [show-all]="false"
            [autoresize]="true"
            [original-size]='true'
            [fit-to-page]='true'
            [render-text]='false'
            (page-rendered)="pageRendered()"
            ></pdf-viewer>
</div>
```

**In your component file:**

```
  // called after pdf page is rendered
  pageRendered() {
    this.pdfComponent.pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = 'page-fit';
  }
```

That's it. Please note, you will notice a flicker or glitch when pdf is updated or browser screen is resized. It is because, `ng2-pdf-viewer` changing the height according the it's settings and then when pdf page is rendered, we change it to the `page-fit`. I hide the pdf for a while when it updates and then show after it loads the settings to the `page-fit`.

Definitely, there are some good approaches to do this. But, this is the only one, I have found after a search of months.

Comment: now zoom property is not working, any solution for that?

Comment: Yes, You can check the solution on Github [here](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/493#issuecomment-565024329)

Answer (score 2):

Use `[fit-to-page]="true"` option to fit the PDF in the page.

```
<pdf-viewer
   [src]='"./assets/images/userFiles/" + file.fileName'
   [original-size]="false"
   [render-text]='false'
   [show-all]="false"
   style="display: block; height: 400px;"
   (after-load-complete)='afterLoadComplete($event)'
   (page-rendered)='pageRendered($event)'
   (pageChange)='pageChange($event)'
   [fit-to-page]="true">
</pdf-viewer>
```

It should work with combination of `[original-size]="true"`.

Comment: It does not work. I have used `[original-size]="true"` with `[fit-to-page]="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which not the best one to fix my issue, as the others not working with me.

1- You need to get notified when rendering of the pdf is done

```
<pdf-viewer
.....
 (page-rendered)="pageIsRendered()>
</pdf-viewer>
```

2- You need to select the element with the class *'ng2-pdf-viewer-container'*
And change style.

3- Apply the style *'display:contents'* on the selected element when pdf is rendered.

Like that:

```
pageIsRendered() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('ng2-pdf-viewer-container')[0].style.display = 'contents';
}
```

No other solutions worked for me, After a long search, I've fixed it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these methods:

1. **use (page-rendered) event function to edit the currentScaleValue of the pdfViewer.**

in the above approach I was getting an error *"Property currentScaleValue does not exist on type PdfViewer"*.

2. Use **[fit-to-page]="true",[original-size]="true"** option to fit the PDF in the page.

This approach also didn't work for me.

I used this approach: **style="position: unset"**

```
<pdf-viewer
  [rotation]="0"
  [original-size]="false"
  [show-all]="true"
  [fit-to-page]="false"
  [zoom]="1"
  [zoom-scale]="'page-width'"
  [stick-to-page]="false"
  [render-text]="true"
  [external-link-target]="'blank'"
  [autoresize]="true"
  [show-borders]="false"
  style="position: unset"> 
</pdf-viewer>
```

And it worked without any issues.